# Game of life does not print correctly C++

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I have some code for the game of life that takes the users input and displays that input as to which cells they entered as alive, but it always prints a row of four * no matter what. I've messed around with changing things a lot of different ways, but it either still prints the same thing, or doesn't display anything at all. I've done searching around multiple forums and websites, but every code i find is done completely different, which is something i would expect (including code from stackoverflow).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#include <memory.h>

int main ()
    {
    const long MaxCols (10);
    const long MaxRows (10);
    const time_t WaitTime (3);

        bool Board [MaxRows + 2] [MaxCols + 2];
        long CurrCol;
        long CurrRow;
        time_t StopTime;
        long Generation;
        long OriginalArray[MaxRows][MaxCols];
        long NewArray[MaxRows][MaxCols];
        long Neighbors;

        do
            {
        cout << "Enter a row and col for the living cell: ";
        cin >> CurrRow >> CurrCol;
            } while (CurrRow != 0 && CurrCol != 0);

        for (Generation = 1; ; Generation++)
            {

            //Display the current generation on the board
            system("cls");
        cout << "\tCurrent Generation: " << Generation << endl;
            for (CurrRow = 1; CurrRow <= MaxRows; CurrRow++)
                {
                for (CurrCol = 1; CurrCol <= MaxCols; CurrCol++)
                    cout << (Board [CurrRow + 2] [CurrCol + 2] ? ' ' : '*');
                cout << endl;
                }
            //Loop to determine nieghbors
            for(CurrRow=1; CurrRow <= MaxRows + 2; CurrRow++) 
                {
                cout << endl;
                for (CurrCol = 1; CurrCol <= MaxCols + 2; CurrCol++)
                    {
                    if (OriginalArray[CurrRow][CurrCol] == '*')
                        {
                            Neighbors = (OriginalArray, CurrRow, CurrCol);
                            if (Neighbors != 3 || Neighbors != 4 )
                                NewArray[CurrRow][CurrCol] = ' ';
                            else
                                NewArray[CurrRow][CurrCol] = '*';
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        Neighbors = (OriginalArray, CurrRow, CurrCol);
                        if (Neighbors != 2 || Neighbors != 3 )
                            NewArray[CurrRow][CurrCol] = ' ';
                        else
                            NewArray[CurrRow][CurrCol] = '*';
                        }
            cout << "Touch any key to halt the program";
            StopTime = time(0) + WaitTime; // time(0) gives the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970
            while (time (0) < StopTime)     // keep looping until the current time catches the stop time
                if (_kbhit())               //true if the user has hit a key, false if not hit a key
                    {
                    cout << "\nBye" << endl;
                    exit(0);
                    }
                else;
    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing around is no way to debug a program. When it doesn't behave as you expect your first step should be to try to understand why. By making what, at your level of experience, will basically be random changes to your code you will just make things worse. As Oli mentioned a debugger is the best tool for this. You should learn how to use yours.

Looking at the code there are probably lots of errors but one error jumps out at me which is this

```
Neighbors = (OriginalArray, CurrRow, CurrCol);
```

I've no idea why you think this will count the number of neighbours but trust me it doesn't. I suppose you took a guess and then when the compiler didn't complain you assumed the guess was right. I'm afraid not.

So that's the bit to concentrate on first. You need some new code to count the number of live neighbours. Have a think about that.

There's no code above to enter values into Board. Here some code to do that. It's correct as far as it goes, but that doesn't mean it will work with the rest of your code which needs *a lot* of work.

```
// baord uses false for dead cells and true for living cells
bool Board [MaxRows + 2] [MaxCols + 2];

// initially make the whole board dead
for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows + 2; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < MaxCols + 2; ++j)
         Baord[i][j] = false;

// now ask the user for some live cells
for (;;)
{
    cout << "Enter a row and col for the living cell (0 0 to quit): ";
    int i, j;
    cin >> i >> j;
    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
         break; // user entered 0 0 so quit loop
    Board[i][j] = true; // set position i,j to live
}
```

The two parts that were missing from your code were initially setting the whole Board to dead, and secondly once you have got the coordinates for a live cell from the user you did nothing to set that cell to live.

One other thing that's confusing me about your code is that you have different size boards

```
    bool Board [MaxRows + 2] [MaxCols + 2];
    long OriginalArray[MaxRows][MaxCols];
    long NewArray[MaxRows][MaxCols];
```

Why does Board have `+ 2` and the others don't. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: The neighbors may currently be messed up, but that isn't the problem I'm currently focusing on. As for the debugger, i used the "start debugging" option, but it really didn't tell me anything that looked useful.

Comment: @Prstorero What a debugger does is let you run your code line by line, and look at the values of variables as you go, it's incredibly useful and every professional programmer probably uses one every single day. Find a tutorial if you can, it's perfect for sorting out this kind of problem.

Comment: I get some whacked out value for the "Board" with:
 +  Board 0x0097fbd4 {0x0097fbd4 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..., 0x0097fbe0 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..., 0x0097fbec "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..., 0x0097fbf8 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..., ...} char[12][12]

No idea what this means or what steps to take for fixing it haha

Comment: Yep, well if you look at your code you will see that you never give Board any initial values  so it's just filled with garbage (amazed I didn't spot that earlier).

Comment: What you need at some point is code like this `Board[i][j] = ' ';` or `Board[i][j] = '*';` for whatever values of i and j you require.

Comment: Well if i give it something like Board == [CurrRow] [CurrCol]; then i get some error saying "expected a { introducing a lambda body".

Comment: So what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Board has 144 cells, so you have to give all 144 cells a value, that means writing a loop or two.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of the two for loops i already have for counting the CurrRow and CurrCol?

Comment: I'm not sure what loops you're refering to. But it's true that at no point in your code do you give the array Board any values, so it contains garbage. If you want to give the array Board some values then you have to write some code that does that. This is very basic stuff. The thing is some of you code above looks like you more or less know what you are doing. But I'm beginning to suspect that you're just cutting and pasting stuff you've found on the internet and are just trying to mash it together and hope it works. You need a better understanding of basic C++ syntax and concepts.

Comment: If you could explain *what* values you want in the array Board then I could show you the code to do that.

Comment: Actually this isn't from the internet, it's from my notes. We just don't get things explained well enough to us for anyone to be able to do a project without help.. The board should contain the users input where i ask for "Enter Enter a row and col for the living cell: " so if the user enters 5 and 5, row 5 column 5 should have an * in it while the rest are blank. I think the code we were provided was meant more or less to work with a set value we would enter rather than being able to take input and display it properly. That's our problem is we get code for a way that we don't even use/learn.

Comment: I'll update my answer with code for that. Hopefully it will help, but I think you have a lot of work still to do. The code is along way from working.

Comment: I also looked at our book in the array section (since this has some stuff to do with them), but the way the book explains things, it's very difficult to follow along and actually understand what it's talking about.

Comment: I think you just need to think a little more carefully what the code you have actually does. The fact that you hadn't written any code to give the Board array some values is something that should be obvious. You have to spell out in great detail precisely what you want the computer to do. It will do everything you tell it (no matter how stupid) and nothing that you don't (no matter how obvious). So if you don't give a variable a value it won't have one (or more precisely it will have a garbage value). I'm guessing you're being taught lots of advanced stuff when really it's the basics you need.

Comment: You're correct with being taught the more advanced stuff. It's programming fundamentals 1, and yet by the third project we're programming calculators and doing palindromes by lab 6. We really aren't covering many basic essentials that would make the class much easier. I think it's because our professor has been doing C++ since a few years after it existed, he doesn't think about core basics. Another problem is we don't exactly build up step-by-step with our labs. We'll do one thing then something completely different the next class.